# Maven Dependence Folder Is Not Showing In Project Explorer Using Eclipse Neon

Tags: maven, selenium

Hi i have created one maven project but dependency folder is not showing in project explorer can anybody help me whats wrong i am new to eclipse.[image]

Answer (score 0):

right click on project and go to maven and click on 'update project'.... after that jar file will be download then you can get the folder.

Answer (score 0):

The *Maven Dependencies* classpath container will only be shown if your `pom.xml` actually has dependencies. Open the *Maven POM Editor* for the `pom.xml` file, go to the *Dependencies* tab, and check whether there are any dependencies listed. If not, add one (for example, to *Group Id* `commons-lang`, *Artifact Id* `commons-lang`, *Version* `2.6`). As soon as you save the `pom.xml`, the *Maven Dependencies* node should show up in the *Package Explorer*. (Note: It will vanish again if you delete the last dependency from the `pom.xml`.)